# Using vals from scala package object in java

Tags: java, scala, package

I have a Scala package object with vals declared in it. So I can use common objects without each time importing all of them.

However, I'd like to use these definitions in Java also, however Java does not allow importing of anything called 'package' which is the name of the class created by Scala.

Is there a way around this, that I can have these package objects and import them into Java

**Update**
Followed the accepted solution. However, added an intermediate class for readability:

package.scala:

```
package nl.mysoft.scalapackage

package object easy {
  val one = 1
}
```

Intermediate class:

```
package nl.mysoft.javapackage;

import nl.mysoft.scalapackage.easy.package$;`

public class EasyE {
  public static final package$ e = package$.MODULE$;
}
```

And usage:

```
package nl.mysoft.javapackage.usage;

import static nl.mysoft.javapackage.EasyE.e;

public class EasyTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(e.one());
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying something similar, but in my case one is not an val, but object. How to access it, can you help me? Tried to use your example, but it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

ex.scala.package.scala:

```
package ex

package object scala {
  def one = 1
}
```

ex.java.Test.java:

```
package ex.java;

import ex.scala.package$;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(package$.MODULE$.one());
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx mate :-)  Even I was facing this issue