# Access sbt config def from java

Tags: java, scala, sbt

This is in reference to [Using vals from scala package object in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516361/using-vals-from-scala-package-object-in-java)

The example shows that the package object has a package declaration at the top of the file.  My question is how to access it when it does not.

Example:

```
package object sbt  {

def config(s: String): Configuration = Configurations.config(s)


}
```

This is found in the sbt source code.  How can I access the function `config` from Java?

Answer (score 0):

`sbt.package$.MODULE$.config("abc");`

figured it out :)